# C# Loading An EXCEL into DataGridView with blank cells causing DGV display error

Tags: c#, sql

While upload an EXCEL to C# DataGridView, I notice my Blank Cells is causing issue when display the information:

[Display Mistake](https://i.stack.imgur.com/054Xn.png)

You notice the Alloy Type is replacing the Tool Size bcs it's blank.
**How can I display my Column as Null is the cell is empty?**

My Code:

```cs
using (OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog() { Filter = "EXCEL Workbook|*.xlsx", Multiselect = false })
{
    if (ofd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        using(XLWorkbook workbook = new XLWorkbook(ofd.FileName))
        {
            bool isFirstRow = true;
            var rows = workbook.Worksheet(1).RowsUsed();
            foreach (var row in rows)
            {
                if (isFirstRow)
                {
                    //Add Headers
                    foreach (IXLCell cell in row.Cells())
                        dt.Columns.Add(cell.Value.ToString());
                    isFirstRow = false;
                }
                else
                {
                    dt.Rows.Add();
                    int i = 0;
                    foreach (IXLCell cell in row.Cells())
                    {
                        dt.Rows[dt.Rows.Count - 1][i++] = cell.Value.ToString();
                    }
                }
            }
            dgvOrders.DataSource = dt.DefaultView;

            //Adding CheckBox to the front of the DataGridView
            DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn checkBoxColumn = new DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn();
            checkBoxColumn.HeaderText = "Select";
            checkBoxColumn.Width = 59;
            checkBoxColumn.Name = "checkBoxColumn";
            dgvOrders.Columns.Insert(0, checkBoxColumn);
        }
    }
}
```

I want to display my Cell as empty and when I do an INSERT INTO, it will write as *null* in the database.

Comment: What happens when you debug your two `foreach (IXLCell cell` loops?

Comment: Which °IXlCell` implementation are you using, ClosedXML, DevExpress or something else. The ClosedXML version has a `TryGetValue` method that may help. Why is this tagged `sql`. It should be tagged with whatever library you are using

Answer (score 0):

I'm using this library: **ExcelDataReader**.

This code is for getting the Excel file:

```
private void GetExcel()
    {
        OpenFileDialog openFile = new OpenFileDialog() { Filter = "EXCEL Workbook|*.xlsx", Multiselect = false };
        if (openFile.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            string FilePath = openFile.FileName;
            List<List<string>> table = new List<List<string>>();
            List<string> row;
            using (var stream = File.Open(FilePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
            {
                using (var reader = ExcelReaderFactory.CreateReader(stream))
                {
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        row = new List<string>();
                        for (var i = 0; i < reader.FieldCount; i++)
                        {
                            var value = reader.GetValue(i)?.ToString();
                            row.Add(value ?? "");
                        }
                        table.Add(row);
                    }
                    SetValueInDataGridView(dataGridView1, table);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

And this code is for setting the values in the DataGridView:

```
private void SetValueInDataGridView(DataGridView dataGrid, List<List<string>> values)
    {
        DataTable table = new DataTable();
        //Set columns in datatable from top row in Excel sheet
        //for (int i = 0; i < values[0].Count; i++)
        //{
        //    table.Columns.Add(values[0][i]);
        //}

        //Set columns in datatable
        for (int i = 0; i < values[0].Count; i++)
        {
            table.Columns.Add($"Column{i + 1}");
        }
        //if Set columns in datatable from top row in Excel sheet use this
        //values.RemoveAt(0);

        foreach (var row in values)
        {
            object[] dataRow = new object[row.Count];
            for (int i = 0; i < row.Count; i++)
            {
                dataRow[i] = row[i];
            }
            table.Rows.Add(dataRow);
        }
        dataGrid.DataSource = table;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this overload of the cells method:

```cs
public override XLCells Cells(Boolean usedCellsOnly)
```

Setting `usedCellsOnly` to false, should return the empty ones as well:

```cs
foreach (IXLCell cell in row.Cells(false))
{
    dt.Rows[dt.Rows.Count - 1][i++] = cell.Value.ToString();
}
```